# Understanding `-Rghc-timing` output

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc

Basically the title - if I run `stack ghc -- SomeFile.hs -Rghc-timing`, and then receive the following output:

```
<<ghc: 32204977120 bytes, 418 GCs, 589465960/3693483304 avg/max bytes residency (15 samples), 8025M in use, 0.001 INIT (0.000 elapsed), 10.246 MUT (10.327 elapsed), 21.465 GC (23.670 elapsed) :ghc>>
```

Does that mean:

- When compiling, GHC used a total of 8,025 MB of memory
- When compiling, GHC took a total of around 33 seconds in wall-clock time to complete

Basically, I want to make sure that it's as I think it is - that GHC's compilation time and memory usage is being measured, rather than anything to do with the program at runtime.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this line shows the statistics for the GHC compiler itself, while it was compiling your code.  It is unrelated to the "runtime" performance of the resulting compiled program.  The meaning of the various statistics is documented in the manual under the `-t` option, [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-options-to-produce-runtime-statistics).

And yes, while compiling your program, GHC allocated a maximum of 8025MB of memory from the operating system and took about 34 seconds of wall clock time, (24 in the garbage collector and 10 in the mutator).